# Pass a “char *“ pointer to a function

Tags: c++, file, pointers, txt

I set up a class to read the file.
Pass a pointer of type char * to the function, which writes the file to the memory unit that the pointer points to.
Finally, I look forward to reading the contents of the file through the pointer outside the function.
But the result didn't live up to expectations.
Inside the program, there is a result output.
But on the outside, there are no results. I don't know why.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace my
{
  class File
  {
     File() = default;
     ~File() = default;
     bool ReadTo(char * _out, const char * _path);
  }
}

bool  my::File::ReadTo(char * _out, const char * _path)
{
        std::ifstream fs;
        //infs lengfsh;
        fs.open(_path);

        fs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        long len = fs.tellg();
        
        //goes well at this,output normally
        printf("my::File::ReadTo >> len:%d\n",len);

        fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        _out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

        fs.read(_out, len);

        //goes well at this,output normally
        printf("my::File::ReadTo >> out:%s\n",_out);

        fs.close();

        return true;
}


int main()
{
    char * txt;
    my::File mf;
             
    mf.ReadTo(txt,"x:\\xxxx\\demo.txt");

    // result shows : NULL
    debug("demo.txt >> \n %s\n",txt);
}
```

Comment: Why did you put `ReadTo`  in a stateless `class`? As it is it would be better as a free function. Also, don't use `malloc`/`free`, use `new[]`/`delete[]` (if you must to manual memory management)

Comment: You are using many features of C in your C++ program when there are better ways to achieve your objective using C++ features, such as using `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`, `std::string` instead of `char*`, `printf` instead of `std::cout << ...`.

Comment: `_out` needs to be either a `char**` or a `char*&`.  Plus `main` needs to free the pointer according to how the memory is allocated in `ReadTo`.  A better solution would be to return a `unique_ptr` to ensure the memory is released in the appropriate fashion.  Alternatively the memory allocated in `my::File` could be owned by the class and freed in its destructor.  You could alternatively use a `std::vector<char>` in `File` to store the data.  Furthermore, you should allocated an extra byte and store a 0 there to ensure any `printf` etc doesn't stray into uninitialised memory.

Comment: In fact, I don't quite understand what "stateless class" is. I just think it's very flexible to use pointers here, because the file size is not known. Outside the program, I just need to provide a pointer, and the program in the class can do almost everything.

Comment: @anti-gravity Stateless means that it (the `my::File` instance) doesn't keep any information in itself. There are uses for such classes but in this case I see none. It just makes it harder to call the `ReadTo` function since you must first create a `my::File` instance. You _could_ make it stateful (and useful) by letting the `File` class manage (`new[]` and `delete[]`) the pointer to the data though.

Comment: Re: "_I just think it's very flexible to use pointers here, because the file size is not known._" - Sure, but it's also a bit hard to make use of pointers "owning the data" in a safe way. There are standard C++ classes that does this work for you, like `std::string` and `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `char * _out` will be *a copy of* what is passed, so modifying that won't affect what is passed.

You should add `&` to that (both declaration and definition) like `char * &_out` to make it a reference so that modification to that will be refrected to what is specified as the argument in caller.

Also make sure what is read is a C-style string (a sequence of character terminated by a null-character). In other words, don't test your program with a file that doesn't contain any byte having value 0x00. Otherwise, the `printf()` will go reading out-of-range and something dangerous may happen.